# Nested for loop with JSON file

Tags: json, r, for-loop

I don't think this question has been asked before, I can't seem to find it.

I have a nested JSON file that I want to extract certain values from. I toyed around with `sapply` and then finally settled on using a nested `for loop` sequence, see below:

```
for(Factor in fund$Factors)
{

  print(Factor$Name)

  for(FactorGroup in Factor$FactorGroups)
  {

    print(FactorGroup$Name)

    for(Model in FactorGroup$Models)
    {
      print(Model$Name )

      for(Position in Model$Positions)
      {

          print(Position$Symbol)
          print(Position$Quantity)
          print(Position$Risk)
          print(Position$MaxRisk)
          print(Position$Daysleft)

      }
    }
  }
}
```

Using this I can extract exactly what I need, but it does it on a line by line basis so the output looks like this:

```
[1] "factor 1"
[1] "factor group 1"
[1] "model"
[1] "position 1"
[1] 1
[1] -769.1946
[1] -7433.627
[1] 14
[1] "position 2"
[1] 5
[1] -3724.63
[1] -12062.5
[1] 76
```

This continues on for roughly 900 lines. What I'm wondering is if they're is a better way to organize this output. Ideally, I would like to concatenate each full sequence into a vector and then go to the next loop. For example, with this our output above would read something like:

```
[1] "factor 1" - "factor group 1" - "model" - "position 1" - 1 - -769.1946 - -7433.627 - 14
[1] "factor 1" - "factor group 1" - "model" - "position 2" - 5 - -3724.63 - -12062.5 - 76
```

And this would iterate until it's looped through the entire file (e.g.,through factor 2, factor group, etc.)

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: What you need is `cat` which does not add a new line to your output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try use `cat` in place of `print`. Then right before the last closing parenthesis, add

`cat("\n")`

`print` prints a new line every time you use it. `cat` will append to the same line.

Sample script

```
for(Factor in fund$Factors)
{

  cat(Factor$Name)
  cat(" - ")

  for(FactorGroup in Factor$FactorGroups)
  {

    cat(FactorGroup$Name)
    cat(" - ")

    for(Model in FactorGroup$Models)
    {
      cat(Model$Name )
      cat(" - ")

      for(Position in Model$Positions)
      {

          cat(Position$Symbol)
          cat(" - ")
          cat(Position$Quantity)
          cat(" - ")
          cat(Position$Risk)
          cat(" - ")
          cat(Position$MaxRisk)
          cat(" - ")
          cat(Position$Daysleft)    
      }
    }
  }
  cat("\n")
}
```

Comment: cat(Position$Symbol"\n")

Comment: I know this is not correct, but wasn't sure what you meant.

Comment: Oh I think this is what you meant: cat(Position$Symbol, sep = "\n")

Comment: This is not what I meant. \n will add a new line, so you only want that at the outermost loop.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks. This worked perfectly. One more questions. Is there a way to store each string result as a vector and name it as iterates through. So now each string starts with the Factor name and then adds in all the corresponding data, and goes to the next factor. Could before going to the next factor, the for loop store that current factor and concatenated data in a vector with any name, e.g., x, y z? Let me know if this doesn't make sense.

Comment: You probably want a list with each list item being a vector of the data for each factor.